# Finding Inverse Fourier Transform of found Fourier Transform

Tags: complex-analysis

So I have the equation $f(t) = e^{-at^2}$ where $a>0$. First I found the Fourier Transform by solving

$F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-at^2}e^{-kt}dt$

from this i got $F(k) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a}}e^{\frac{k^2}{4a}} $

Now I am trying to solve for the inverse fourier transform to confirm that this is in fact the correct transform.

So, we know the inverse fourier transform for this function would be

$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a}}e^{\frac{k^2}{4a}}e^{ikt}dk$

In solving this I first combined the two exponentials and completed the square yielding.

$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a}}e^{\frac{1}{4a}(k+i2at)^2}e^{at^2}dk$

From here we can pull our the second exponential since it has no k dependence, and then  I used the known integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-at^2}dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}$ to solve the integral after doing the substitution $u = k+i2at$ and $du = dt$. This ultimately yield me $-ie^{at^2}$. This is not equal to the original $f(t)$ I have, so I am a little confused. I tried using mathematica to solve for the fourier transform of my original $f(t)$ and it yields the result I got. Then, I tried it to solve the inverse fourier transform, and got the same answer that I have. Is there some trick that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you computed the FT incorrectly in the first place. It should be $-k^2/4$ in the exponential:
$$
\begin{align*}
F(k) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a t^2} e^{-i kt} dt\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a\left( t^2 + \frac{i\, k\, t}{a} - \frac{k^2}{4a^2}\right)} e^{-\frac{k^2}{4a}} \, dt\\
&= e^{-\frac{k^2}{4a}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a\left(t + \frac{i \, k}{2a}\right)^2}\, dt\\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a}}  e^{-\frac{k^2}{4a}}.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, checking to make sure by computing the inverse you get:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(t) &= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a}} e^{-\frac{k^2}{4a}} e^{i k t} \, dk\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{4a}\left( k^2 + i \,4 \,a\, k\, t - 4 a^2 t^2\right)} e^{-a^2 t} \, dk\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{a}} e^{-a^2 t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{4a}\left( k + 2ait\right)^2}\, dk\\
&= e^{-a t^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Oh, good call! It looks like I forgot the $i$ in my exponential in the Fourier Transform. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. And yeah, these computations sure can be messy, so it's easy to make a mistake! If you found this helpful, then I would appreciate if you accepted my answer. Thanks! =D